# Hibernate naming strategy

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, spring-boot

I am building a REST webservice with Spring (Boot) and am trying to use hibernate as orm mapper without any xml configuration.

I basically got it to work, but I am stuck with a configuration issue.
I instantiate `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` as `@Bean` in a @Configuration file.

I set `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` as in the following example -> this seems to work for creating the tables if they do not exist (column names are camelCase like in my @Entity classes) but when a query is executed, hibernate "forgets" about this naming configuration and tries to use another kind of naming strategy with under_score_attributes --> obviously those queries fail. Is there any other property I need to set?

Or another way of configuring the properties preferably *without* adding a `cfg.xml` or `persistence.xml`?

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();   
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
props.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy");
lef.setJpaProperties(props); 
lef.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` allows the naming strategy (and all other JPA properties) to be set via local external configuration.  For example, in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl_auto: create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Comment: but where do I find documentation for these properties?!

Comment: and to answer my comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/application.yml this is quite useful...for all autoconfiguration properties

Comment: The current place to find properties is http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Comment: Specifically http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this particular property using programmatic properties?  Or a `hibernate.properties` file in the package root?  Or a JVM system property?  All are described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic).

From my experience, there are sometimes difficult to diagnose Hibernate problems if you insist on not using any XML (which would be my preference as well).  If nothing else works, you may be forced to define a configuration file at least.

Answer (score -2):

I got the solution now.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={HibernateJpaAuto Configuration.class})
```

The JpaAutoConfiguration must be excluded. Still I think this might be a bug, as normally it should automatically "stand back" when I use my own @Configuration.

Comment: This rather defeats the purpose of using Spring Boot. See my answer below.